# Elasticsearch How long does it take to create a snapshot?

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I am using aws elasticsearch.
To upgrade from version 6.x to version 7.7, we plan to create a manual snapshot.
But I have to estimate the working time.

There are about 4,000,000,000 searchable documents, and the size is about 6TB. When it was 12,000,000, it took about 3 minutes. How long does elasticsearch take at most? Has anyone ever experienced it?

please reply. My head hurts so much.

Comment: The answer is very simple: it depends :-) but 6TB will take some time for sure. If it's the very first snapshot, you can extrapolate from the 12M docs one, so about ~16h-ish

Comment: Can you share the source of the 12M docs one you mentioned? Is the snapshot creation time and the restoration time similar?

Comment: That's what you mentioned in your question `When it was 12,000,000, it took about 3 minutes`

Comment: I'd like to know something like an accurate guide document rather than a general guess. For example, the time it takes for each size

Comment: Again: The answer is very simple: it depends :-) You won't find any concrete numbers anywhere and no one can tell you that, because that depends on your custom use case and environment

Comment: Thank you so much. Thanks to this, the question was solved a little.